# solrj getCountDistinct() return null?

Tags: lucene, solrj

I am trying to get unique value of a field with the code:

```
query.set("q","*:*" );
query.setGetFieldStatistics(true);
query.setGetFieldStatistics("popu_s");

QueryResponse rsp = solr.query(query);

FieldStatsInfo stats = rsp.getFieldStatsInfo().get("popu_s"); 
System.out.println(stats.getCount());
System.out.println(stats.getCountDistinct());
```

stats.getCount() gives the correct count. However, stats.getCountDistinct() always returns null.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
To make `getCountDistinct()` return a value, one needs to add this

```
   query.addStatsFieldCalcDistinct("popu_s", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCountDistinct()` in [FieldStatsInfo](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/53981795fd73e85aae1892c3c72344af7c57083a/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FieldStatsInfo.java) is null because it was not provided when creating the FieldStatsInfo object (what was returned from `solr.query(query)`).

There is no guarantee that any of the fields in this pojo are populated.

As an alternative try using `stats.getCardinality()` although again there is no guarantee this is poulated.

Comment: Thanks. `stats.getCardinality()` returns null as well. Then how to get countDistinct to work?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer its dependent on `solr.query(query)` returning you a fully populated response with all the values you need. That cannot be answered here as we do not know your dataset/ queries etc, and it becomes out of scope for SO.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have control over `solr.query(query) returning you a fully populated response`? I my code I already specified `query.set("q","*:*" );` which is asking for all documents.

Comment: Query q can be anything you want.